# Disable SVN externals with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use svn externals for sharing binary information on a repository. The information changes from time to time depending on what is needed in a metal shop facility.

Adding new externals to the repository is time consuming and I would like to keep the repository as minimal as possible always, so searching the information at the repository is quite straightforward.

So far I need to delete the external property I do not want to see anymore, commit the changes and update it at the shop plant. I understand that this is the way this works so maybe there´s no better solution, but what I would like to do is to disable (comment this property out temporarily) so I do not have to add it again in the future in case I need it.

It looks like this is not possible on Tortoise´s GUI, only add new, edit info or remove it, but not commenting. Has anyone found a workaround for this ?

Alternatively, where does Tortoise keep this information ? Can I edit the configuration file by hand ?

I tried the tools in Tortoise but there seems to be none for this task

Comment: Externals are a core Subversion feature. They're stored as `svn:externals` property. You can't "comment out" properties, but I guess you can rename them, like `disabled:svn:externals`. Not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: Not the perfect solution, but good enough for what we need, thanks Álvaro. One further question: once the repository is updated, all previously commited files are gone but the folder remains, even if absolutely empty. I get a message from Tortoise warning me about this: "Left local modifications". Is this what is supposed to happen ?

Comment: "Alternatively, where does Tortoise keep this information?" Tortoise doesn't keep this. Tortoise is a GUI for subversion. Subversion keeps all its information in the `.svn` directory in your working copy. "Can I edit the configuration file by hand?" Possible but a very bad idea. You can use subversion's CLI e.g. `svn propdel`, `svn propset` etc. You could write a batch file for your recurring tasks.

Comment: Thanks Friedrich. I admit I have been lazy and have not read the info, at least not lately. I was hoping I could add a #,* or whatever it would take to comment out a single line , thus "disabling" an external property. If that is not possible and since I hardly ever use the command line to interact with SVN, it is easier to just create a new "useless" property just to keep the information about the url saved there and remove the external with Tortoise´s tools.